# Shift-F5 and Shift-F6 don't work in Midnight Commander on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, midnight-commander

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> does not copy file.
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> does not rename file.

How I can reassign these key combinations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Midnight Commander <kbd>F15</kbd> is copying files (with renaming) in the same directory and <kbd>F16</kbd> is renaming files in the same directory.

In keyboard preferences of Terminal I assigned to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> Action value of <kbd>F15</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> Action value of <kbd>F16</kbd>.

Action values:
<kbd>F15</kbd> is `\033[28~`
<kbd>F16</kbd> is `\033[29~`

Answer (score 8):

For some reason the actual shift key number sent is 2 lower than pressed.

For ex. Shift-F8 sends Shift-F6.

Also mentioned here: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2885

I remapped the codes as mentioned above in Terminal preferences and it works now.

Comment: Say what now???

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu, it seems that it is the other way around, Shift-F4 gives me the rename file dialog, Shift-F6 deletes a file. Your comment helped me figure this out though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the shift key?

I can copy files just fine in midnight commander when using either <kbd>F5</kbd>or <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>.

Same for move/rename with <kbd>F6</kbd> (and alternative <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> for when the function keys are not working or not available).

Comment: Shift key allows to copy/move to the same MC panel. Yes, I need it. These combinations work well on Win machine.

Comment: Might depend which way round you have your F-keys set. If they normally turn the volume up/down etc, then use Fn/Shift/F5 etc

Comment: @Tetsujin It didn't help.

Comment: Did you see https://gist.github.com/sgergely/3793166 ? It doesn't mention shift/F-keys.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is a good point for some laptop and some very annoying (often called 'multi-media' keyboards which combine useless keys with function keys and where you actually have to press Fn to use the regular function keys).

@ Junky: OK, darn. I tested it on a BSD machine which is the closest thing to OS X which I have access to (though I remember it working the same way on Linux). No idea why OSX does it differently.  *ponders deleting answer since it obviously is not the right one.*

Answer (score 0):

For **iTerm2**, based on Junky's answer: In *Settings / Keys / Key bindings*, add a preset. Set the keyboard shortcut as <kbd>Shift+F6</kbd>, and choose to *Send Escape Sequence*. As that already sends an <kbd>ESC</kbd>, you only need to add `[29~`

It gave me a warning that this shortcut is already used somewhere, but I didn't encounter any issue.